# Using python screws up the shell (and/or terminal?)!

Tags: terminal, bash, command-line, macports, python

## The problem

Simply opening and closing the Python sub-shell screws up my shell (or *possibly* the terminal?). It seems to remove the shell's ability to print any text I enter, including newlines after I enter a command.

The problem occurs for python3.4, python2.7, and python2.6, but not for python2.5.

It hasn't ever occurred before (that I've noticed), and it doesn't happen for other software packages I've used (VIM, Emacs, etc.).

I've confirmed that it breaks using Apple's standard Terminal (Version 2.2.3 [303.2]), iTerm2 (build 2.1.1), and XTerm (269).

Interestingly, it breaks under `bash`, but not `zsh` or `csh`.

### Example behavior

To demonstrate, I do the following (`$SHELL` is `/bin/bash`):

1. Run `which python3.4`.
2. Run `python3.4`.
3. Hit the Return key once, then enter `exit()` into the Python shell.
4. Hit Return two more times.
5. Enter `python3.4 --version`.

Here's what I see for a few of the primary versions of Python I have installed:

#### Python3.4 -- problematic

```
myself@localhost:~$ which python3.4
python3.4 is /opt/local/bin/python3.4
python3.4 is /opt/local/bin/python3.4
myself@localhost:~$ python3.4
Python 3.4.3 (default, Aug 24 2015, 17:25:38)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 3.0 (tags/Apple/clang-211.12)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> exit()
>>> myself@localhost:~$ myself@localhost:~$ myself@localhost:~$ Python 3.4.3
myself@localhost:~$
```

#### Python2.7 -- problematic

```
myself@localhost:~$ which python2.7
python2.7 is /opt/local/bin/python2.7
python2.7 is /usr/local/bin/python2.7
python2.7 is /usr/bin/python2.7
python2.7 is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
python2.7 is /usr/bin/python2.7
python2.7 is /usr/local/bin/python2.7
python2.7 is /opt/local/bin/python2.7
myself@localhost:~$ python2.7
Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug 24 2015, 11:54:49)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> exit()
>>> myself@localhost:~$ myself@localhost:~$ myself@localhost:~$ Python 2.7.10
myself@localhost:~$
```

#### Python2.6 -- problematic

```
myself@localhost:~$ which python2.6
python2.6 is /opt/local/bin/python2.6
python2.6 is /usr/bin/python2.6
python2.6 is /usr/bin/python2.6
python2.6 is /opt/local/bin/python2.6
myself@localhost:~$ python2.6
Python 2.6.9 (unknown, Aug 24 2015, 17:53:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> exit()
>>> myself@localhost:~$ myself@localhost:~$ myself@localhost:~$ Python 2.6.9
myself@localhost:~$
```

#### Python2.5 -- It works!

```
myself@localhost:~$ which python2.5
python2.5 is /usr/bin/python2.5
python2.5 is /usr/bin/python2.5
myself@localhost:~$ python2.5
Python 2.5.6 (r256:88840, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:45)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> exit()
myself@localhost:~$
myself@localhost:~$
myself@localhost:~$ python2.5 --version
Python 2.5.6
myself@localhost:~$
```

Running it in `zsh` or `csh` seems to work just fine:

#### Zsh

```
myself@localhost:~$ zsh
localhost% which python3.4
/opt/local/bin/python3.4
localhost%
localhost% python3.4
Python 3.4.3 (default, Aug 24 2015, 17:25:38)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 3.0 (tags/Apple/clang-211.12)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> exit()
>>> %                                                                           
ra%
ra%
ra% python3.4 --version
Python 3.4.3
localhost% exit
myself@localhost:~$
```

#### Csh

```
myself@localhost:~$ csh
Running csh
[localhost:~] myself% which python3.4
/opt/local/bin/python3.4
[localhost:~] myself% python3.4
Python 3.4.3 (default, Aug 24 2015, 17:25:38)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 3.0 (tags/Apple/clang-211.12)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> exit()
>>> [localhost:~] myself%
[localhost:~] myself%
[localhost:~] myself% python3.4 --version
Python 3.4.3
[localhost:~] myself% exit
exit
```

## My thinking so far:

The fact that the behavior seems the same for three terminals makes me think it's not a terminal issue.

The fact that it works in Zsh and Csh but not in Bash makes me think it's a shell issue.

The fact that the versions that break (3.4, 2.7, 2.6) are all installed under `/opt/local/bin/` (MacPorts's usual install location), but the version that works (2.5) is installed under `/usr/bin/`, makes me wonder if some recent MacPorts update (pushed maybe up to 20 days before Aug. 24, 2015??) may have broken something that makes Python and Bash not work together!

Comment: A guess - the macports pythons aren't committed with GNU readline - try installing  pyXX-readline

Comment: Beside @Mark solution and until the issue is fixed, when you quit python with `exit() `, `quit()`, or `control D` type `reset` at the prompt (it will not be echoed back to the terminal) and wait until the prompt reappears.

Comment: @Mark: That worked! If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There appears to be an issue with recent Macports builds of python see this [bug](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/48807?cversion=0&cnum_hist=11)

A workaround is to install pyXX-readline (py35-readline has been produced just for this bug)

Another is to install python addding the +readline variant